# Capistrano can't run rake

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, capistrano

I am trying to run Capistrano and it can't run rake on my server. When I try to run `cap deploy` I get the following errors:

```
*** [err :: ] /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:779:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem rake (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
*** [err :: ] from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:214:in `activate'
*** [err :: ] from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1082:in `gem'
*** [err :: ] from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bin/rake:18
```

In my deploy file I have added `set :rake, '/home/.gems/bin/rake'` (which is the correct path to my rake) to make sure I am running the right rake.

When I login to my server via SSH I can run rake just fine

Comment: Any progress? I'm getting a similar issue. "sh: rake: not found command finished in 347ms" from cap deploy:migrate

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to call

```
bundle exec rake ....

# Updated post
set :default_environment, {
  'PATH' => "..../usr/local/rbenv/shims:/usr/local/rbenv/bin:$PATH"
}
```

Comment: I've tried adding `set :rake, 'bundle exec rake'` to my deploy file and I get the same error

Comment: Maybe the ssh user has only a limited $PATH environment... Could you check if $PATH is correct? Maybe you have to add the paths.. See my updated post

Comment: I've tried that too, same error. I think it is finding the rake file because if I remove `set :rake` and `set :default_environment` I get errors about not finding rake that are different then the ones above...

Comment: Did you include your own absolute rake path? The path above in my solution might wont work for you, since I use rbenv..!